A problem in Weinberg QFT Vol.1 Chapter 3
This is related to problem 5 of Weinberg's QFT vol.1 Chapter 3. The standing wave states $\Psi_\alpha^0$ are defined by a modified version of Lippmann-Schwinger equation,
\begin{equation}
    \Psi_\alpha^0 = \Phi_\alpha + \frac{\mathscr{P}}{E_\alpha -H_0} V \Psi_\alpha^0
\end{equation}
where $\mathscr{P}$ is the principal value function (I think) and $\Phi_\alpha$ are eigenstates of $H_0$ with energy $E_\alpha$. Consider the matrix defined by $K_{\beta \alpha} = \pi \delta(E_\beta -E_\alpha)(\Phi_\beta , V \Psi_\alpha^0) $. The problem is to show that $K_{\beta \alpha}$ is hermitian and express S-matrix in terms of K- matrix.
I can show that K is hermitian. However I couldn't write S matrix in terms of K matrix. Here's a summary of my approach:

I  equated the two equations I got by using Lippmann- Schwinger equation for $\Psi_\alpha^+$ and $\Psi_\alpha^0$ in $(\Psi_\beta^0, V \Psi_\alpha^+)$.

Multiplying by $\pi \delta(E_\beta - E_\alpha)$ and inserting completeness relations I got,
\begin{align}
      \pi \delta(E_\beta - E_\alpha) T_{\beta \alpha}^+ -K_{\beta \alpha} &= \pi \delta(E_\beta - E_\alpha) \left[\int{d\gamma \frac{(V\Psi_\beta^0,\Phi_\gamma)(\Phi_\gamma, V \Psi_\alpha^+)}{E_\alpha-E_\gamma + i \epsilon}} - \mathscr{P} \int{d\gamma \frac{(V\Psi_\beta^0,\Phi_\gamma)(\Phi_\gamma, V \Psi_\alpha^+)}{E_\beta-E_\gamma}} \right] 
  \end{align}

Using the identity $(E_\alpha -E_\gamma + i \epsilon)^{-1}=\frac{\mathscr{P}}{E_\alpha -E_\gamma} - i \pi \delta(E_\alpha -E_\gamma )$ I get \begin{align} \pi \delta(E_\beta - E_\alpha) T_{\beta \alpha}^+ = K_{\beta \alpha}-i \pi \delta(E_\beta - E_\alpha) \int{d \gamma K_{\beta \gamma} T_{\gamma \alpha}^+}\end{align}
The LHS goes straight into the expression for S matrix. However I couldn't get rid of the $T_{\gamma \alpha}^+$ in RHS. Any hint on how to proceed in this way or an alternative method would be helpful.


